# Based on Job parameters configure Sprig Batch Writer

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I created a a simple spring batch job using spring boot that reads from our database and writes to a topic. I also had a hook that I could comment out the topicWriter and write to a csv file during development. Both are working by commenting one out and running the other writer. (topicWriter or writer). Business now wants to be able to run adhoc, topic or writer. So I opted to pass in a output param that contains either topic or csv. Upon reading it looked like I could use a decider, but this may be wrong. As it stands now with the below code complains about duplicate step and is looping when I try to run.I was unable to figure out how to run without a starting step, so I created a do nothing tasklet because the job needed a start step before the decider. So I think I got this all screwed up. Any ideas of a solution or directions?

```
   @Bean
public Job job(@Qualifier("step") Step step) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get(BatchConstants.JOB_NAME).listener(jobListener())
            .start(step).next(decider()).on("COMPLETED").to(step1(null,null)).from(decider()).on("FAILED").to(step2(null,null)).end().build();
}


  @Bean
protected Step step() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
            .tasklet(new Tasklet() {
                public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) {
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;

                }
            })
            .build();
}

@Bean
protected Step step1(ItemReader<someDto> reader,
                    ItemWriter<someDto> topicWriter) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get(BatchConstants.STEP_NAME)
            .<someDto, someDto> chunk(BatchConstants.CHUNKSIZE)
            .reader(reader)
            .writer(topicWriter) // write to kafka topic.
            .build();
}


@Bean
protected Step step2(ItemReader<someDto> reader,
                    ItemWriter<someDto> writer) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get(BatchConstants.STEP_NAME)
            .<someDto, someDto> chunk(BatchConstants.CHUNKSIZE)
            .reader(reader)
            .writer(writer) // writes to csv
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Singel step you can define this using **@StepScpoe** . Based on job parameters you can select the writer.

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    protected Step step2(ItemReader<someDto> reader,
                        ItemWriter<someDto> writer ,ItemWriter<someDto> topicWriter,"#{jobParameters['writerType']}") final String type ) {

                            ItemWriter<someDto> myWriter;           
                            if(type.equals("topic"))
                            {
                                myWriter=topicWriter;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                myWriter=writer;
                            }

        return stepBuilderFactory.get(BatchConstants.STEP_NAME)
                .<someDto, someDto> chunk(BatchConstants.CHUNKSIZE)
                .reader(reader)
                .writer(myWriter) 
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: Configured application and applied logic posted and it works great. Thanks so much for your input.